# Speed up sql query where elements in two columns must belong to a common set

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a postgres database where I have a table listing all the nodes in a graph and a table listing all the edges between those nodes.  What I want to be able to do is specify a subset of all the nodes and then retrieve all the edges between those nodes.

The edge table has two columns to indicate which nodes it joins: `left_node` and `right_node`.  So the query for the edges has to return edges where both the left_node *and* the right node are in the set of nodes specified eg. if there are 100 nodes but I'm interested in the connection between 20 of them.

I created the query below that checks to see that each node is in the set.  It works but does not scale; with 4.6M edges and a set of just 10 nodes, the query takes 3 minutes (macbook pro M1 32GB ram).  I need to scale to +100,000 nodes

Is there a better way to do this?

```
-- edge query
edge_query = """
    select *
    from edges ed
    where ed.left_node_id in ({})
    and ed.right_node_id in ({})
"""

-- execute query in pandas (or your favourite dbase ide)
import pandas.io.sql as sqlio

edges_retrieve = sqlio.read_sql(edge_query.format(<text_nodes_list>),<connection>)
```

Comment: How will the 100,000+ list of nodes be supplied to the query?

Comment: At the moment just as a long list of strings eg. 'node_1', 'node_2', ...  Which seems pretty kludgy.

Comment: Please update the question with actual table DDL, including indexes, and the results of running `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)` on the query. There's not enough information provided to support specific suggestions.

Comment: If you have a graph data structure then why not use a graph database to hold your data? Graph databases were invented because the existing RDBMSs didn't scale well with this sort of problem

Comment: @NickW actually I'm currently working with both types of db's and doing comparisons.  Fact is if most of your business' data is in a RDBMS spinning up another db and maintaining it for a relatively small number of use-cases can be an unwanted licensing expense.  So far I've found that once the graph is defined, almost all of what I want to do is handled perfectly well by RDBMS.  This case here is the first real challenge and I think it's my approach that's suboptimal.

Comment: @MikeB2019x if you can load the nodes-list into a table instead of putting them in an IN clause it would be better. Also, do you have indexes on left_node_id and right_node_id?

Comment: @user2773289 the nodes-list is a subset of nodes from the table of all the nodes.  is the suggestion that I create a table just for the subset?  Also haven't done indexing yet.

Comment: @MikeB2019x by nodes-list I meant the set that goes into the IN clause that you are passing in as a parameter right now (<text_nodes_list>). Also, indexes will help improve performance.

Comment: I guess the answer is pretty pedestrian.  I indexed the node and edge lists which increased speed by 100x but increased the footprint of each table by ~1.5x.  @user2773289 if you put that in an answer plus the bit about passing in the node list as a table (which I also did) I'll select it.

Comment: @MikeB2019x I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve performance,please load the set that goes into the IN clause (<text_nodes_list>) into a table. Also, create indexes on columns used in the where clause.